# What's the difference between openssl_pkcs12_export() and openssl_x509_export() PHP functions?

Tags: php, openssl

This is probably a stupid question, but as far as I can tell there's not much difference aside the additional parameters in pkcs12 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More importantly than the formats themselves, the pkcs12 export stores off the private key along with the certificate, whereas the x509 one just stores the certificate.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs, the output file format differs:

[openssl_pkcs12_export()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs12-export.php) stores x509 ... in a PKCS#12 file format.

[openssl_x509_export()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-export.php) stores x509  ... in a PEM encoded format.